# SkiaSharp SkData is null after Encoding Image

Tags: c#, skiasharp

I have a function to generate the favicon's for my website. This works just fine when I want to generate a PNG, however when I try to create the `favicon.ico` the Encoded method returns a null SkData which naturally results in `skData.AsStream()` exploding in a NullReferenceException.

```cs
var data = memoryStream.ToArray();
using var src = SKImage.FromEncodedData(data);

var info = new SKImageInfo(size, size, SKColorType.Rgba8888);
using var output = SKImage.Create(info);
src.ScalePixels(output.PeekPixels(), SKFilterQuality.High);

var type = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower() == ".ico" ? SKEncodedImageFormat.Ico : SKEncodedImageFormat.Png;
using var bitmap = SKBitmap.FromImage(output);
var skData = bitmap.Encode(type, 100);
await using var skStream = skData.AsStream();
```

What is the proper way to resize an input image, and generate an output file in Ico format?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you do everything right, but SkiaSharp just doesn't support encoding/decoding of all formats for all platforms.

[Which image formats are supported on which platforms?](https://github.com/rust-skia/rust-skia/issues/389)

But you can use some other approach to write the bitmap to ico file, for example this:
[Dynamically Generating Icons (safely) (CodeProject)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7122/Dynamically-Generating-Icons-safely)